# In Visual Studio is there an easier way to open source code through a PDB then to step into a function call from that library?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, pdb-files

I want to be able to browse the source and set a debug point without having to hunt for a way to get the file open.  I know you can open the original source and detach/reattach the debugger but that is a pain to do every time you run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remember the name of the method you want to debug by heart, you can Add New Breakpoint (Ctrl+B) and type "MyClassName.MyMethodName" (enter). That will put a breakpoint in the beginning of that method, and when you run, as soon as it's hit, the file will open.

Comment: That's much better then how I was doing it.  I will mark this as answer in a couple days if nobody comes up with a better solution.

Comment: Cheers. BTW,you don't have to enter the method's full name, you can just enter "MyMethodName" and Visual Studio will still find the method properly and put a breakpoint there. If you enter a method name that has differnet overloads or the same method name exists in different classes, Visual Studio will ask you which of the methods you want, and will offer to put a breakpoint in all of them.